# Java : regex split() based on 2 delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a string when space is followed by comma.

My input String :

```
go back, to work !  ,2012-10-01 07:01:45,,  1
```

Output Expected:

```
"go back, to work !"    
"2012-10-01 07:01:45,,1"
```

Code I tried:

```
String[] b1=a1.split("[\\s,]");
```

But this splits the string only based on whitespaces. I want to split it when there is both whitespace and comma not just either one. What should I do?

Comment: Your string also contains `,, 1` at the end - and it doesn't seem to show in the expected output - but you don't mention that it should get "cleaned"

Comment: @alfasin : yes, the output should have only 2 parts. I have edited the post.

Comment: Your square brackets `[\\s,]` defines a _character class_ and means _any **one of**_ the characters in the class — **not** the sequence of characters `space-comma`.

Comment: I fixed the fix on the expected output. From the verbal description, the second string should include the `,,1`, they shouldn't have been outside of the quoted string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split on **space followed by comma**:

```
String[] b1 = a1.split("\\s,");
```

`[\\s,]` is a character class and it will split on space or comma.

Comment: The OP is not clear on the requirements, but he *does* state that the requested output should separate `2012-10-01 07:01:45,, 1` into two string: `2012-10-01 07:01:45` and `1`. I'm afraid that it will be *very* difficult to find a regex that does exactly what he wants (which also means that regex is probably *not* the right tool for the job in this case).

Comment: I dont want to split it based on whitespace "or" comma.  I want to split it when there is whitespace followed by comma.

Comment: Yes that's what my answer provides i.e. `split on whitespace followed by comma`

Comment: @anubhava : I am sorry, but it splits only on whitespace.

Comment: @keerthupraveen No, this regex works. Make sure you really used his regex.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to split a string when a white space, then comma occurs.

```
String[] b1 = a1.split(" ,");
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on space followed by comma using `("\\s,")` will not give you the desired output of

```
"go back, to work !"

"2012-10-01 07:01:45"

1
```

The output will be

```
go back, to work !

2012-10-01 07:01:45,, 1
```

Either you can use comma followed by space or space followed by comma using `"\\s,|,\\s"` then you will get below output

```
go back

to work !

2012-10-01 07:01:45,

1
```

However it's still not same as what you wanted. You might want to clarify your requirement.

Comment: I have edited my post. I want the output to be in 2 parts only. However ("\\s,") doesn't solve the problem. It splits only on whitespaces.